# I have one shell script name AIC.sh need to forward all the output to my E-mail

Tags: shell, typescript

I have created one Script which contain different commands which are intended t o run on multiple server and named AIC.SH. I want the output directly emailed to my Email id.

Comment: I am Trying
./AIC.sh> output ; mail -s "SUbject" "MS8545@example.com" < AIC.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mail(1) utility found on most linux systems.

```
echo "This is a test email" | mail --subject "Test" _user_
```

Hope this helps